# MS ACCESS- Trimming a Text and STR([Number]) Concatenation

Tags: string, ms-access, concatenation, iif

I know the `STR(expression)` formula adds a space at the beginning of the field. When I use `Trim` during a concatenation, it does not remove the space. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

```
IIf(Len([Cust #])=1,Trim("00000" & Str([Cust #])),"")
```

result:

```
00000 2
```

Should be:

```
000002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Trim` trims of spaces from beginning and end of a string, not from the middle. should be:

```
IIf(Len([Cust #])=1,"00000" & Trim(Str([Cust #])),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

No leading space with `CStr()` instead of `Str()`.

```vb
? Trim("00000" & Str(2))
00000 2
? Trim("00000" & CStr(2))
000002
```

So you wouldn't need `Trim()`.

```vb
? "00000" & CStr(2)
000002
```

Actually you don't absolutely need any of those functions.  Simple concatenation will implicitly cast the number to a string.

```vb
? "00000" & 2
000002
```

`Format()` could also give you what you want.

```vb
? Format(2, "000000")
000002
? Format(2, String(6, "0"))
000002
```

Comment: I don't know if it's an issue with Access 2016 but the simple concatenation wouldn't work initially so I tried to use CStr and it didn't recognize it either. I didn't try format though, that's good to know.